Compiling some source files using 'make' gives errors: apparently, a missing file
I'm trying to get Quantum Espresso installed in linux.
After introducing this into the terminal:
$ sudo apt install git wget build-essential

$ sudo apt install g++ gfortran liblapack-dev

$ sudo apt install libfftw3-dev libopenmpi-dev

Then,
$ git clone https://github.com/QEF/q-e.git

$ cd q-e

./configure

As a result, I get this
-----------------------------------------------------

ESPRESSO can take advantage of several optimized numerical libraries
(essl, fftw, mkl...).  This configure script attempts to find them,
but may fail if they have been installed in non-standard locations.
If a required library is not found, the local copy will be compiled.

The following libraries have been found:

 BLAS_LIBS= -lblas

 LAPACK_LIBS=-L/usr/local/lib -llapack  -lblas

 FFT_LIBS= -lfftw3

Please check if this is what you expect.

If any libraries are missing, you may specify a list of directories
to search and retry, as follows:

  ./configure LIBDIRS="list of directories, separated by spaces"

Parallel environment detected successfully.\

Configured for compilation of parallel executables.

For more info, read the ESPRESSO User's Guide (Doc/users-guide.tex).

-----------------------------------------------------

configure: success

Until this point, I think everything goes as it's supposed to.
The problem comes out when I use the command make:
$ make all

test -d bin || mkdir bin

( cd UtilXlib ; make TLDEPS= all || exit 1 )

make[1]: Enters in the directory '/home/jesus-abf/Documentos/Servicio social/QE/q-e/UtilXlib'

Makefile:49: make.depend: File or directory doesn't exist

make[1]: *** There is no rule for building the target 'make.depend'.  Stop.

make[1]: Exits from the directory '/home/jesus-abf/Documentos/Servicio social/QE/q-e/UtilXlib'

make: *** [Makefile:209: libutil] Error 1

I don't really understand why that file simply doesn't exist. I'm sure it's an error because I know for a fact that I should get binaries in the bin folder and it's empty.

What is the version of Ubuntu?

Did you follow the instructions "For more info, read the ESPRESSO User's Guide (Doc/users-guide.tex)". It may be a LaTex document, for more info, check everything in the Doc subdirectory.

The issue is almost certainly that the space in your path breaks the script that generates the make.depend files (as part of the ./configure process). For example, given:
$ pwd
/home/steeldriver/src/sub dir/q-e

then executing make depend produces
Checking dependencies...
( if test -x install/makedeps.sh ; then install/makedeps.sh ; fi)
install/makedeps.sh: 134: test: /home/steeldriver/src/sub: unexpected operator

directory LAXlib : not present in /home/steeldriver/src/sub dir/q-e/install
install/makedeps.sh: 134: test: /home/steeldriver/src/sub: unexpected operator

directory FFTXlib/src : not present in /home/steeldriver/src/sub dir/q-e/install
install/makedeps.sh: 134: test: /home/steeldriver/src/sub: unexpected operator

directory UtilXlib : not present in /home/steeldriver/src/sub dir/q-e/install
install/makedeps.sh: 134: test: /home/steeldriver/src/sub: unexpected operator

.
.
.

all dependencies updated successfully

(the last message is unhelpful - since the dependencies were not in fact updated successfully). You probably missed these messages in the ./configure script output.
The simplest solution is to rename the Servicio social parent directory to something without whitespace - such as Servicio_social - and then run make depend again in the top level q-e directory.
